# Form input arrays in angular

Tags: angularjs, html, node.js, express, angular-ngmodel

I am learning Angular.js and i've come to a problem that should probably be simple, but I can't seem to find an answer on.

I want to create form inputs with the value of "connectedTeams", like this in html:

```
<input type="text" name="connectedTeam[]"> 
<input type="text" name="connectedTeam[]"> 
<input type="text" name="connectedTeam[]">
```

I have tried the following in angular...

```
<input type="text" name="connectedTeams[]" class="form-control" ng-model="user.connectedTeams">
```

...but it is binding the same value to all 3 inputs. I know in my mind that this makes sense, but I can't seem to figure out how to tell it that ng-model is **user.connectedTeams.[]** ***(user > connectedTeams > add to an array.***

I hope this makes sense enough for someone to provide a quick answer.

Comment: The `name` property has no effect on the binding...

Comment: i.e. <input type="text" ng-model="user.connectedTeams[2]">?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 ng-model="user.connectedTeams[0]"
 ng-model="user.connectedTeams[1]" and so on
```

You can put it in a ngRepeat, so you don't need to repeat your code like above.

FYI, name is only used for validation in Angularjs.

Comment: Thank you. I had just figured this out and was going to answer my own question. So I guess that if i was doing an add / remove row, i'd just set a variable like $scope.i = 0; and then every time i click add it would increase or decrease the value of $i?

Comment: you should read ngRepeat doc. There is an $index you can use.